# Simulate LAN to test XNA network

Tags: c#, xna, network-programming

I'm currently working on a XNA game and I need to try the local network part over internet, using system link. I've tried with Hamachi but Windows Live Games was not compatible with that.  Is there some way to do this?

Comment: do you get any errors? why not compatible? have you tried another software? i moved away from hamachi, connection and sync problems everywhere ... i am using [tungle](http://www.tunngle.net/) works ... well ... better ;) good luck, have fun!

Comment: Don't know why it's not compatible, but it isn't. There seems to be reg. hacks to solveit but I haven't tried that. I'll try tunngle and see if that works, thank you @nilsK

Comment: Maybe port-forwarding?